# ¿Cómo guardar la redirección de una sitio web con JavaScript o Python?

Tags: javascript, python, url, http-get

estoy buscando la forma de obtener la URL a la que se redirecciona al usuario y almacenarlo en una variable para luego ser enviado a mi base datos. Por ejemplo:

URL principal: https://miweb.com/normas
URL redireccionado https://miweb.com/?listanormas=Key.153516t

resultado a obtener:
var urlFinal = 'https://miweb.com/?listanormas=Key.153516t'

Comment: Considera que se puede dar el cierre de tu pregunta ya que no se ajusta a [ask] pues solo expones aquello que buscas conseguir pero no lo que has intentado

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el módulo `requests`, por ejemplo:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.github.com')
response.url
```

O si necesitas la lista de objetos de respuesta puedes usar  `Response.history`:

```py
import requests
responses = requests.get("http://www.google.com")

for response in responses.history:
    print(response.url)
```

Referencias:

- [Requests- redirection and history](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)
- [http - Python Requests library redirect new url - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)